# SAPUI5 Call method's model from xml view

Tags: sapui5

Is it possible to call a method from model?

For example I have extanded my JSON Model and add a function called hello_world.

In my XML view I want to call the method of this model from and event off a control like below :

```
 <Select change="{cl_vehicule>}.hello_world">
                    <items>
                        <core:Item text="1" key="1"/>
                        <core:Item text="2" key="2"/>
                    </items>
                </Select>
```

Is it possible ?

If yes how to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible for the following reasons:

1) *change* in your Select control is an *event*, so it has to be associated with a function. This is not the same thing as calling the function. Please notice that you do not add () after the method name when using a event

2) *cl_vehicule* in your example should be the name of an association between a control and model. Models have no name. The name you put before > in a data binding is specified in the manifest or in a *setModel* method call. In other words, the same model can be associated with different controls but using different names.

3) Using {} means that you are using method bindProperty or bindAggregation to that control. These methods are defined in ManagedObject class. Those cannot be used in events.

4) As UI5 uses MVC paradigm, a View should never contact a model directly

---

So, you should basically use the *change* event associating it with a function from your controller. In that function you have different ways of getting your extended model to call a method.